# Morphism of distinguished triangles where one of the arrows is a quasi-isomorphism

Tags: derived-categories, modules, triangles, cones, quasi-isomorphism

Let $R$ be any ring and let $A\to B\to C\to [1]$ and $A'\to B'\to C'\to [1]$ be distinguished triangles of complexes of $R$-modules. Let $f:A\to A'$, $g:B\to B'$ and $h:C\to C'$ be morphism of complexes such that $(f,g,h)$ is a morphism of distinguished triangles.

I wonder whether the following statement is true:

> If $f:A\to A'$ is a quasi-isomorphism, then there is a quasi-isomorphism $\operatorname{cone}(g)\stackrel{\sim}{\to} \operatorname{cone}(h)$.

Clearly, if all the involved complexes are concentrated in degree $0$, the statement follows from the snake lemma. Is this true in general?

Many thanks !

Comment: That's true when the middle commutative square (containing $g$ and $h$) is homotopy cartesian (see Neeman's book).

Comment: Actually, that would be equivalent to your morphism $(f,g,h)$ being *middling good* in the sense of Neeman, Amnon. 1991. “Some New Axioms for Triangulated Categories.” Journal of Algebra 139 (1): 221–255. https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(91)90292-G. Therein, you find an example of morphism of triangles which is not middling good, but $f$ there is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you @FernandoMuro for your reference. So what I actually understand from there is the following: if $f$ and $g$ are given, from the octahedral axiom there exists $h:C\to C'$ such that $(f,g,h)$ is a morphism of (distinguished) triangle. For this $h$, we further have that a distinguished triangle $C(f)\to C(g)\to C(h)\to [1]$ (and hence, if $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism, then $C(f)$ is acyclic and $C(g)\to C(h)$ is a quasi-isomorphism). But this is not true for all $h$. Is that right?